# Perl GetFiles function with MBCS (Japanese) characters returns question marks

Tags: perl, encoding, internationalization

I have this code below and it returns "C:?????.log" instead of "C:\あいうえお.log" which is what I expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use Win32::Clipboard;
use Encode;

my $clipboard = Win32::Clipboard();
my @files = $clipboard->GetFiles();

foreach my $f (@files) {
    print $f;
}
```

What I did was that I created a text file "C:\あいうえお.log”. I pressed Ctrl+C on a Windows Explorer on Windows 11 environment after selecting the log file. I opened a Dos prompt and went to the location where this perl script above is saved and run it. I get "C:?????.log" instead of "C:\あいうえお.log”。 I have Japanese fonts installed so when I do "dir c:". The log file is correctly listed without any character corruption.

When I tried to write a similar script with $clipboard->GetText() instead of GetFiles(). After copying Japanese text, it printed it correctly. It looks like "GetFiles" are not handling Japanese file names correctly. This GetFiles script correctly worked in Windows 10 environment.

I tried encoding STDOUT or output of GetFiles but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to use the [GetAsFormat](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Clipboard#GetAs(FORMAT)) method with `Win32::Clipboard` to tell it to encode as Unicode.

I tried something like this and it copied my Unicode text correctly:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use Win32::Clipboard;
use Encode;

my $clipboard = Win32::Clipboard();
my $files = $clipboard->GetAs(CF_UNICODETEXT) || die 'Something went wrong!';

foreach my $f (split /\s/, $files) {
    print $f;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand "GetAs" function, it works just like GetText but you can specify the encoding. For me, GetText did work and what didn't work is "GetFiles" function which retrieves file names when I press Ctrl+C after selecting files on Windows Explorer. I tried the code you suggested and does return "text" but not when I tried to use it instead of GetFiles. Let me know if I am not understanding your suggestion.

Comment: @ShoichiTakasaki I'm not sure exactly. What do you get back when you use `GetAs`?

Comment: I just get an error message as below (this doesn't happen if I just copy Japanese text as opposed to press Ctrl+C after selecting a file in Windows Explorer)

Something went wrong! at ./test_clipb3.pl line 9.

Comment: @ShoichiTakasaki Hmm, perhaps your terminal does not support UTF-8? I am not sure why it is broken.

Comment: I don't think it is my terminal because "GetText" (and GetAs) works to retrieve Japanese text. Just GetFiles doesn't work.